# Excel VBA regular expression error

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Hello I'm having some issue tring to get the regular expression code  below to work.
I'm getting a application-undefine or Object-Undefine error

the text box is on  user form.

the error is occurring on the line "Set allMatches = regEx.Execute(TextBox1.Text)"
not sure what I missed.

```
Dim regEx As Object

Dim allMatches As Object

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2)[AM|PM]"
        .Global = True
End With

Set allMatches = regEx.Execute(TextBox1.Text)


If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If
```

Comment: Just a crazy thought. Is TextBox1.Text valid? Can you successfully do a MsgBox on it?

Comment: What version of Excel and what textbox control are you using? IE ActiveX

Comment: the textbox is just on a form and yes I can access with a MsgBox, and I'm using excel 2010 with XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some googling and looking, I found the problem:
its with the pattern:

```
 .pattern = "\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2**)** [AM|PM]"
```

it turns out you will get the 5017 error if the pattern is not valid.

by changing the ")" to the proper closing "}" the error was solved.

```
 .pattern = "\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2**}** [AM|PM]"
```

I would thought that if the pattern did not match then you would get a false return, not so..

Comment: There's probably a difference between a non-matching pattern, and a syntactically invalid pattern. It sounds like you had the latter, but good job for solving your own question!

Answer (score 0):

So it is possible that you are accessing the Textbox incorrectly.  Without knowing how you setup the textbox I am going to guess that its held in the shapes collection.  You could look for the textbox and then set the allMatches such as below

```
Dim shp As Shape
'loop through the shapes on the sheet - assuming you are working with sheet 1
For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
    If shp.Name = "TextBox1" Then
         Set allMatches = regEx.Execute(shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Sorceni, the text box is place right on the form it does not nest inside any frame or or shape..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are accessing the textbox correctly, the `[AM|PM]` poses a problem in my mind.
It seems to me this would match one character: A, M or P, or M.

If it were me I would use `[A|P]M-` then the first letter could be A or P and the second letter must be M.
That would also assume it is only looking for capital letters.
To include lowercase, `([Aa]|[Pp])[Mm]` OR maybe better `[AaPp][Mm]`.